# Troubleshooting CS:GO Issues

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I've just purchased CS:GO and game's constantly crashing to desktop without any error message.

I've already tried most of the solutions online, such as:

- Deleting csgo.exe and then repairing game files through Steam
- Adjusting video settings to low
- Disabling multicore rendering
- `cl_disablehtmlmotd "1"`

I now reinstalled Windows, but issue persists. My PC specs are as follows:

- i5-3570k OC'ed to 4.2GHz
- 8GB of DDRM3 memory
- Windforce GTX 670 OC'ed
- Game's installed on my SSD drive
- Latest Windows 10 X64 build

I've been running other games with much higher requirements without any issues, my pc temperature is normal during gaming.

Please help me to find a solution to fix this.

Comment: Step 1 would be to find the log files I think. Are you sure it is using your good graphics card and not the on-board card instead?

Comment: Well, game usually runs in highest settings and is super smooth, doubt that built in video card could work that way.

Comment: Ah, so it does start, just crashes randomly in a game or something? The debug log should be located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Counter-Strike Global Offensive or whatever your install location is now. It might give you a hint of what is going on.

Comment: Correct, I can play it but it just exists to desktop at random times without any error message, so far I haven't seen any pattern that could identify what could be the issue. Perhaps you know how log files should be named? There must be some naming convention.

Comment: Did you try updating your nvida drivers ?

Comment: Of course. It's up to date.

Comment: I thought multicore rendering is more helpful because it utilizes more of cpu power to ease load. Am I wrong?

Comment: @MandeepJain It's supposed to be, but some users have reported that disabling it resolved their crashes.

Comment: Interesting. Will keep that in mind. My game always crashes when I play Nuke, but yours is a random case so its tough to find whats causing it

Comment: Dont you get even a 'csgo.exe has stopped working' window?

Comment: @MandeepJain No, I don't have it. It just jumps to desktop and that's it, no error message and no logs in Windows System viewer... I've reduced video settings and that has reduced crashes, but they still exist.

Comment: Than its evident that something from outside the game is crashing it. Virus maybe? Or some tool that monitors cpu usage and shuts the program down if it takes too much resources? Also, does csgo have some issues with overclocking?

Comment: @MandeepJain Not sure if it can be virus, besides that - I've done a fresh Windows installation. Now when you said about CPU usage, could it be TuneUp Utilities that might shut game down? And as for overclocking - no idea...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48714/discussion-between-mandeep-jain-and-evaldas-buinauskas).